# How to encode and decode the string properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsstring

I get the dictionary from web service and this dictionary contain encoded key-value pair. I used some code for decode this key-value.

Code no. 1 :

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[dict valueForKey:@"desc"] cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
```

But when I run this code then it get crashed and got the error `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'`

When debugging it, dictionary contain keys & values also "desc" key having a value.

On other side i have one code that worked fine.

Code no. 2:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"desc"]];
```

But almost everywhere in my app, I used code no.1 and its worked very well.

and now i have totally confuse i this error `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'` came while i check dictionary contain keys & values.

Comment: stringWithFormat is used for TypeCasting and format the string not for decode and encode .

Comment: Please show the definition of your string/dict and let us know from/to what you want to decode/encode.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create a C-String from `NSString` and then (back) `NSString` from C-String?

Why not simply

```
NSString *desc = dict[@"desc"];
```

And – as always – **do not** use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC.